# Execute specific tasks within Ansible role

Tags: ansible

How Can I execute certain tasks. For e.g. For below role, lets say i am deploying applications then i need to create general directory and Application1 directory only. How can i deploy only those two tasks?

I have following Ansible directory structure:

```
├── ansible.cfg
├── playbook.yml
└── roles
  └── groups
    └── tasks
      └── main.yml
```

My groups/tasks/main.yml file looks like this:

```
---
- name: Create Directory General
  file:
    path: /tmp/general
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'

- name: Create Directory Application1
  file:
    path: /tmp/Application1
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'

- name: Create Directory Application2
  file:
    path: /tmp/Application2
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
```

Playbook.yml

```
---
- name: Deploy application
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - groups
```

Note: I am already aware of include_role but then it will set one tag to all tasks within role. I do not want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is IMO not a single good answer to this question but since you mentioned [tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html)...

```yaml
---
- name: Create Directory General
  file:
    path: /tmp/general
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
  tags:
    - always

- name: Create Directory Application1
  file:
    path: /tmp/Application1
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
  tags:
    - app1

- name: Create Directory Application2
  file:
    path: /tmp/Application2
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
  tags:
    - app2
```

You can then call your playbook with:

```
# Deploy all apps with common tasks
ansible-playbook playbook.yml

# Deploy only application 1 with common tasks
ansible-playbook --tags app1 playbook.yml

# Deploy application 2 without running common tasks
ansible-playbook --tags app2 --skip-tags always playbook.yml
```

Be careful with the latest one as it will also skip fact gathering by default. See documentation link above for further details.

Comment: So when i run playbook it will pick it up tags from this roles?

Comment: Trying it would answer your question faster than asking ;) Yes, as described in my answer.